# Knowing if a row has the lowest column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a query that updates rows according to their current values.
One of the conditions I'm checking is "if the specific row I'm updating has one column that is the lowest value in the table out of the other rows with 4 identical row values".

So.. for example, my table structure is like so:

```
INTEGER id - PRIMARY KEY
FLOAT lookup
VARCHAR(128) option1
INTEGER option2
INTEGER option3
INTEGER option4
```

I want to know if the row I'm `UPDATE`-ing is the one with the lowest `lookup` value out of all other rows that match the same `option1`, `option2`, `option3` and `option4` values.

How could I implement such a thing in a single query? I'm trying to minimize queries and get the most out of a single query, so I can't use my frontend for this. I can use subqueries and my character limitation for the query is 8192 characters.

Edit:
Sample rows:

```
id | lookup | option1 | option2 | option3 | option4
1  | 1.000  | "a"     | 2       | 1       | 4
2  | 1.100  | "a"     | 1       | 1       | 2
3  | 1.200  | "a"     | 1       | 1       | 1
4  | 1.250  | "a"     | 1       | 1       | 1
5  | 1.300  | "a"     | 1       | 1       | 1
```

A query that I want to be done:

```
UPDATE table SET option2 = IF_LOWEST_IN_TABLE(lookup)? LOWEST:NOT_LOWEST WHERE option1 = "a";
```

The `LOWEST` part should happen for rows of `id` 1, 2 and 3. The `IF_LOWEST_IN_TABLE` and the ternary operators are "placeholders" because I don't know how it should be implemented in SQL.

Comment: Sample data and desired resultset would help a lot.

Comment: also the queries you tried

Comment: @lad2025 @Harish Barma - I have added sample data and an example query. I don't know if I need a resultset like a `SELECT` would do, so I can't know what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: show also the excpected  result  please

Comment: I did. `IF_LOWEST_IN_TABLE(lookup)? LOWEST:NOT_LOWEST` is the expected result. If `lookup` is the lowest in the table, then set the value to `LOWEST` and if not, `NOT_LOWEST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join` and `group by`:

```
UPDATE table t JOIN
       (SELECT min(id) as minid, option1, option2, option3, option4
        FROM t
        GROUP BY option1, option2, option3, option4
       ) tt
       ON t.id = tt.minid
   SET t.option2 = LOWEST
   WHERE option1 = 'a';
```

EDIT:

If you want to set `LOWEST` *and* `NOT LOWEST`, use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
UPDATE table t LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT min(id) as minid, option1, option2, option3, option4
        FROM t
        GROUP BY option1, option2, option3, option4
       ) tt
       ON t.id = tt.minid
   SET t.option2 = (CASE WHEN tt.minid IS NOT NULL THEN LOWEST ELSE  NOT_LOWEST END)
   WHERE option1 = 'a';
```

Comment: How could I perform the other side of the "ternary operator" (`else`) though? As in, `NOT_LOWEST` in my example.